# How to make an object appear in the canvas when you left click in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So what I want is to get an oval onto the canvas of my python work. ( Which is a photo editor project ). "c" refers to the canvas I've made and shaped into a tkinter program in python. How do I make the following code to make an oval pop up in the canvas of my program?( Also if you know how to do a mouse down event please change the "<Button-1>" to the appropriate tag ):

```
def PaintBrushWorking():
    blueBlob = c.create_oval(20, 30, 40, 60, fill = "blue")
    blueBlob.pack()

c.bind_all("<Button-1>", PaintBrushWorking)
```

Comment: On the third sentence of my paragraph I meant "the following code". And on the fourth sentence I meant change the "<Button-1>" to the tag which it allows you to do a left click hold function.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with your coding problem. But about the disappeared "<" and ">": you have to write "&lt;" and "&gt;" instead, like I did when editing your question, see this link for [more information on markup](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). BTW you can always edit your own question: click on the small "edit" beneath the `python`and `canvas`tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the call to `pack`, and then make your function accept an event argument. And finally, you probably want to use `bind` rather than `bind_all`, unless you really want it to draw the oval even if you click on some other widget such as a button or scrollbar.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def PaintBrushWorking(event):
    blueBlob = c.create_oval(20, 30, 40, 60, fill="blue")

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas()
c.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

c.bind("<Button-1>", PaintBrushWorking)

root.mainloop()
```